Customize php.ini settings nixpacks
I am using coolify to deploy apps, coolify uses nixpacks under the hood to build an image.
When deploying a PHP project everything works fine, but I cant figure out or find  anyting in the docs about customizing PHP's runtime settings and / or php.ini config.
On Heroku it was possible to add a .user.ini file (as per PHP standard), I tried to do that for nixpacks aswell but that did not work.
I also found the same question here, but that doesn't solve the issue since he ended up creating a custom Dockerfile.
